# What is the $\mathcal O$ of subtraction-based GCD algorithm?

Tags: algorithms, asymptotics

Subtraction-based algorithm for finding the greatest common divisor works like this:

For two integers a and b (a > 0, b > 0),
if a > b, then gcd(a, b) = gcd(a-b, b)
else if b > a, then gcd(a, b) = gcd(a, b-a). 
else if a = b gcd(a, b) = a

What is the $\mathcal O$ of this algorithm?

Comment: Dijkstra? What would Euclid say? [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm#Implementations) has this method, which it claims was the first version of the solution by Euclid "subtraction-based version".

Comment: @HendrikJan there are some places where it is used under that name (I do not know why) like [here](http://www.ijcaonline.org/volume26/number5/pxc3874253.pdf). Do you think it should be changes to "subtraction-based version"?

Comment: @Evil Indeed, Dijkstra used this method as an example in his 1971 lecture notes on programming: EWD316: A Short Introduction to the Art of Programming: [4. Variables and relations between their values](https://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/EWD/transcriptions/EWD03xx/EWD316.4.html).

Answer (score 4):

Suppose that $a,b$ are the two input numbers. At each step of the algorithm, the sum $a+b$ decreases, since (assuming $a > b$), the new numbers are $a'=a-b,b'=b$, and $a'+b'=a < a+b$ (since we stop when $b=0$). Thus the algorithm terminates in at most $a+b$ steps. This is almost tight: if $b = 1$, then the algorithm terminates in $a$ steps.

Summarizing, on inputs $a,b$, the number of steps (or arithmetic operations) is at most $a+b$, and could be as bad as $a$. In terms of the *length* $n$ of the input (number of bits needed to represent it), the number of operations is at most $O(2^n)$ (since $a,b \leq 2^n$), and could be as bad as $\Omega(2^n)$ (when $a = 2^n,b=1$). Thus the *worst-case* running time (as measured by number of steps) is $\Theta(2^n)$, where $n$ is the input length.

Answer (score 1):

For subtraction-based GCD algorithm (with checking for 0 value and signs of numbers to make it work) the complexity is $\mathcal O(n)$ which is easily seen by using gcd(n, 1) which takes $n$ steps. This steps depend on the *actual value* not like in standard case the *length of the input*, so algorithm is in fact exponential.

Avoiding corner cases the worst case occurs when two numbers are coprime. The property of gcd is that $gcd(ma, mb) = m*gcd(a, b)$. When the numbers are coprime, meaning that in the factorization of a and b there are no common primes, which yields irreducible pair, so algorithm must continue to the only common divisor: 1.

Comment: Can you expand your argument a bit? It is not clear why the worst case happens if the arguments are coprime if you're not terribly familiar with number theory.

Comment: @adrianN I hope it helps, otherwise I have to work a bit more on it, include some examples and take Bézout as help. Thank you for your comment.

Comment: Note that here $n$ is the *value* of the input rather than its length, as usual. In terms of the length of the input, the running time is exponential.

Answer (score 1):

gcd (n, 1) requires n-1 steps. The algorithm is therefore exponential in the size of the inputs.

Answer (score -2):

Try calculating gcd (1, 0) using that "algorithm". It doesn't seem to be an algorithm, because it never finishes. Fix your question.  Also, please think about the problem more carefully before asking.

Comment: The OP explicitly assumes that the inputs are positive.

Comment: I have added this explicit assumption, earlier it was implicit only. @gnasher729 maybe you could consider deleting this answer since you have provided better one?